# How can I register a new REST context?

Tags: filters, rest-api

I'm using the REST API to get datas from Wordpress within my React App.

I've seen that you can filter the responses Wordpress returns by using the filter `rest_prepare_{$this->post_type}` documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/).

I've also seen that you can use a context (*view*,*edit*) parameter when making a rest request; which will alter the responses.

In the [documentation about modifying responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#important-note-about-changing-responses), there is a note that says

> Adding fields is not dangerous, so if you need to modify data, it’s
> much better to duplicate the field instead with your modified data.
> Removing fields is never encouraged; if you need to get back a smaller
> subset of data, use the _fields parameter or work with contexts
> instead.

I would thus use a custom context for my rest requests

But **how do you register a new context** ?

If I just do my requests with a parameter `?context=react` set, I get a `400 (Bad Request)` error.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL is more flexible in general than the built-in REST API, regarding customizing the response. GraphQL is currently not shipped with the WordPress core, but is available as a plugin.

Let's look at the **existing** endpoints for the `WP_Post` object(s).

We note that it is possible to use the [`_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields) query parameter to include specific fields in the general REST response.

Here are few ways we can define new custom schema **contexts**, to the existing endpoints, using the schema setup in:

- `register_rest_field()` when adding new rest fields.
- `register_post_meta()` when adding existing post meta as new rest fields.
- `WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_item_schema()` for the existing rest fields and append new contexts to their item schema via the `rest_{$this->post_type}_item_schema` filter. This filter was added in [47779](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47779).

Let's look at two examples:

### Example: New custom context for a new rest field

Here's an example for adding the new `foo` rest field with the `bar` value for the `post` object type and the custom `wpse_react` *context*:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'foo',
        array(
            'get_callback' => function ( $object ) {
                return 'bar'; 
            },
            'schema'       => array(
                'type'     => 'string',
                'context'  => array( 'wpse_react' ),
                 // ... etc
            ),
            // ... etc
        )
    );
} );
```

Then try e.g. the GET request `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?context=wpse_react` and verify that the new field is displayed under the `wpse_react` context.

### Example : New custom context for existing rest fields

We can filter the existing post type schema with `rest_{$this->post_type}_item_schema`. So for the `post` post type we can add the custom `wpse_react` *context* to e.g. the existing rest fields `date`, `title.rendered` and `content.rendered`:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_item_schema', function( $schema ) {
    // 1st level.
    foreach ( ['date','title','content'] as $item ) {
        if ( is_array( $schema['properties'][$item]['context'] ) ) {
            $schema['properties'][$item]['context'][] = 'wpse_react';
        }
    }
    // 2nd level for the 'rendered' part.
    foreach ( ['content', 'title'] as $item ) {
        if ( is_array( $schema['properties'][$item]['properties']['rendered']['context'] ) ) {
            $schema['properties'][$item]['properties']['rendered']['context'][] = 'wpse_react';
        }
    }
    return $schema;
} );
```

Then try e.g. the GET request `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?context=wpse_react`.

### Extending existing REST controllers

If we need to modify existing endpoints into our own custom endpoints, it is informative to look at e.g. how the **Blocks** controller extends the **Posts** controller to remove fields and change the contexts:

```
class WP_REST_Blocks_Controller extends WP_REST_Posts_Controller
```

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.9/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-blocks-controller.php

where it overrides these methods with:

```
/**
 * Filters a response based on the context defined in the schema.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 *
 * @param array  $data    Response data to fiter.
 * @param string $context Context defined in the schema.
 * @return array Filtered response.
 */
public function filter_response_by_context( $data, $context ) {
    $data = parent::filter_response_by_context( $data, $context );

    /*
     * Remove `title.rendered` and `content.rendered` from the response. It
     * doesn't make sense for a reusable block to have rendered content on its
     * own, since rendering a block requires it to be inside a post or a page.
     */
    unset( $data['title']['rendered'] );
    unset( $data['content']['rendered'] );

    return $data;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Retrieves the block's schema, conforming to JSON Schema.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 *
 * @return array Item schema data.
 */
public function get_item_schema() {
    // Do not cache this schema because all properties are derived from parent controller.
    $schema = parent::get_item_schema();

    /*
     * Allow all contexts to access `title.raw` and `content.raw`. Clients always
     * need the raw markup of a reusable block to do anything useful, e.g. parse
     * it or display it in an editor.
     */
    $schema['properties']['title']['properties']['raw']['context']   = array( 'view', 'edit' );
    $schema['properties']['content']['properties']['raw']['context'] = array( 'view', 'edit' );

    /*
     * Remove `title.rendered` and `content.rendered` from the schema. It doesn’t
     * make sense for a reusable block to have rendered content on its own, since
     * rendering a block requires it to be inside a post or a page.
     */
    unset( $schema['properties']['title']['properties']['rendered'] );
    unset( $schema['properties']['content']['properties']['rendered'] );

    return $schema;
}
```